# Capacity is not visible in TFS ,with all the required access

Tags: tfs, sprint, capacity-planning

I am trying to access my project sprint in TFS. I have given the contributor role with basic access. I am unable to view the capacity from the TFS. I could see task board, backlog and analytics whereas capacity is missing. Please help me to resolve this problem. Let me know if anymore issue description is needed?

Comment: As TFS varies greatly from version to version, can you provide the version of TFS that you are using?

Comment: Version installed in my system is: Team Foundation Server office Integration 2017 update 9 Version: 15.129.28308.1

Comment: Please make sure you are a member of the current team. Have your sprint defined a start and end date? Or has your current sprint past? You can set a sprint in the current period to see if there is a Capacity option.

Comment: All other team members with contributor access are able to see the capacity. I am the only one facing this problem.

Comment: It's quite strange. Is it convenient for you to update your questions and add some relevant screenshots, such as your sprints interface and your security interface?